# Selecting the most informative categorical features for a multi-class ML classification model

Tags: python-3.x, categorical-data, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, multiclass-classification

I have a dataset on all the software installed by a large group of users. I would have to classify the users into one of 4 categories based on which software they installed (each user can install up to 30 pieces of software).

The categories are highly **imbalanced** - one category contains nearly 45% of the users in the training dataset, another - 35%, a third only 15% and the forth - only 5%. Let's say that these 4 categories roughly correspond to 4 different IT job types (e.g. "Software Engineer", "DevOp", "Analyst", etc.).

"Software" is a feature which has high cardinality (above 1000) so using naive one-hot encoding does not seem appropriate.

I would like to identify a subset of informative values/levels for this variable. For instance, a software like an anti-virus program probably does not differentiate well between these categories as all or most users would have it installed. A specialised tool (e.g. IDE) might differentiate better, i.e. its frequency of occurrence might be different within each IT job category.

How to identify such "informative" features using python? Do we use sklearn.feature_selection.chi2? Or do we use sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif? Or is there some other method?